# Do we need stationarity for Bayesian network modelling?

Tags: bayesian, stationarity, bayesian-network

Most of the Bayesian network packages in R dealing with continuous data require data to be Gaussian. Does this necessitate the data should also be stationary in order to run the model?

Comment: "It isn't in a software package, so it must not exist for a good reason" is an unreliable rule of inference.

Comment: Within R packages e.g. bnlearn, you can model dynamic data by setting whitelists/blacklists so that any learned associations respect the time precedence.